# WSM-01775 The policy "oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy" cannot be attached to ResourcePattern "/WLS/oim_domain/UNKNOWN"

Tags: soa, oracle-fusion-middleware, oim

I am unable to make request from OIM to SOA composite due to some policy mapping issue in Oracle Fusion Middleware.

```
at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.BufferedResultsProxy$BufferedResultsHandler.run(BufferedResultsProxy.java:162)
Caused by: oracle.fabric.common.PolicyEnforcementException: WSM-07620 : Agent cannot enforce policies due to either failure in retrieving polices or error in validations, detail= "WSM-01775 The policy "oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy" cannot be attached to ResourcePattern "/WLS/oim_domain/UNKNOWN|#iam-ejb.jar|WS-Client({http://org.identityconnectors.genericws}wsconnector_client_ep#WebservicesConnectorService_pt,wls)" SubjectType "WLS_REFERENCE" of attachTo "binding.client" since it may only be used with "a service endpoint".
```

[image]

Need to remove this policy attachment from this UNKNOWN application. How to do this. Snap is from oracle EM console.